# Google Hangouts plugin iceweasel

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, camera

I tried to make a video call using Google Hangouts running on Raspberry Pi 2 B Model with Chromium working on Raspbian 8. Everything worked well but the RPi-camera had very bad quality on Chromium. Trying to do the same on iceweasel got me stuck at installing Google Hangouts plugin which I couldnt find online.Can anyone help me with this? Or maybe tell me how can I improve quality of camera on chromium?

Answer (score 1):

The quality issue in Chromium is a long standing [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616007)
(related issue [#1498 in pi linux repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1498) and associated [forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=159941)) to do with the way it handles V4L2 devices that advertise a continuous range of resolutions rather than a discrete set.

6by9's [last comment in #1498](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1498#issuecomment-247807044) has a dirty-hack workaround for it.